# programmatically clicking on button in webbrowser control not working

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

from this [page](https://www.logisticsinformationservice.dla.mil/BINCS/begin_search.aspx)

I am trying to load a duns number and hit submit

```
webBrowser1.Document
           .GetElementById("ctl00$cphMainPageBody$txtDUNS")
           .SetAttribute("value",  "116811088");
webBrowser1.Document
           .GetElementById("ctl00_cphMainPageBody_btnSubmit")
           .InvokeMember("Submit");
```

The text enters just fine but when I get to the second line of code nothing happens

for invoke I have also tried "Click"

the target in question is

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cphMainPageBody$btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cphMainPageBody$btnSubmit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_cphMainPageBody_btnSubmit" title="Click to submit your search">
```

note:

My end goal is to get the return page and scrape a peice of data off and repeat
I don't have any need for the webbrowser control if it could be done entirely like

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.gooogle.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

if u don mind do it on server side,

assign value to textbox and call your button event by

```
txtDUNS.Text = "116811088";
btnSubmit_Click(null,null);
```